# Condition variable misconception

Tags: c, multithreading, variables, pthreads, conditional-statements

Suppose I have a tree and suppose I have a condition variable in each node of the tree.

Let's suppose 5 nodes were trying to insert into my tree(which already has 10 nodes)and for a reason, the 5 couldn't insert(they are waiting for some nodes to be deleted), so I make them wait using their condition variable. Now that a deletion is occuring in the tree, I want to check if the ones waiting are waiting on that deletion, so then I want to signal a node, how would I know which thread to signal, do I have to keep track of all the condition variables initially in the inserts?

Suppose on a certain deletion, I want to signal thread 3, which is waiting(along with 2 others), how can I specifically signal thread 3?, would thread 3 still remember what he was trying to insert?

In my delete function, when I signal, I don't know what the condition variable for that thread waiting is since each node has a condition variable, and there can be multiple nodes each with a condition variable waiting. I know a broadcast all will contact all the threads, but how can I do it without that, and specifically signal a thread initially wanted to insert a value 5 in the tree, but since a 5 already existed, it couldn't, and know that 5 has been deleted, it should insert the 5, but along with 5 waiting, there is 1,6,3,2 waiting, and so I have 5 condition variables, and don't know which one is for 5.

This is all in C, using linux.

Comment: I don't quite follow what you're trying to do, but you almost certainly don't want a separate condition variable for each node in the tree.

Comment: @NPE how can I know the context of each thread with just one condition variable?

Comment: @NPE Let me rephrase, suppose I have a tree, which has nodes 2,3,4 already, suppose I want to insert, 2 and 3, but I can't since they already exist, and I wait. When 3 is deleted, I want that thread to be notified that 3 has been deleted, go ahead and insert. When 2 is deleted, I want that thread to be notified, so it can insert 2. When 4 is deleted, nothing should happen.

Comment: Why would you want to wait to add something that is in the tree in the 1st place? Put a node counter and increase it when the node is added twice, and remove for real the nodes when the counter reaches 0?

Comment: @LtWorf, it's a task for me to understand pthread waiting and signalling. Please read my question and try to answer it. I specifically want to use signaling and waiting

Comment: Oh if it's for an assignment is different, I was suggesting a faster solution instead.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you associate the condition variable with the thing it is used to wait for. So, if thread 3 is waiting for node X to be deleted, it might wait for a signal on the condition variable of node X. Thread 3 would not wait for a signal on the condition variable of a node it is inserting. If thread 5 deletes node X, then it would would signal on the condition variable of node X. Thread 5 does not need to know that thread 3 is waiting; it just signals on the condition variable of node X, and pthreads manages the job of notifying threads that are waiting for that condition variable.

I am somewhat concerned that you are deleting nodes and might be deleting the condition variables along with them. If you are deleting node X, you would not want to delete its condition variable until threads waiting on it have been woken, and the condition variable is no longer in use. So your design is unclear there.

Comment: so what is a clear way of designing this. I am being told I can use 1 condition variable, but I don't know how that would work. I was thinking of doing a broadcast all, but then even if that thread wakes up, how would it re-insert?